# Create rough terrain for used in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, world, player, gazebo-worlds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all,
i have to create a world with rough terrain. how shall i do that? somebody can suggest me a good tutorial?

thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11948/create-rough-terrain-for-used-in-gazebo/) by [Maurizio88](https://answers.ros.org/users/1359/maurizio88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2011-11-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use [Blender](http://www.blender.org/), an open-source 3D modelling and animation program, to create my terrains. For example, you could try [this tutorial](http://blender101.blogspot.com/2009/11/terrain-via-height-map-tutorial-blender.html) to get you started. There is also the option to use the [sculpt tool](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IhLuA5kpn2Y) to create terrains. You can also use Blender to create other meshes.

Once I create my terrain, I then export the terrain to Collada 1.4 (.dae) using the built-in Blender Collada exporter. This format is readable by Gazebo.

Finally, to get the terrain into Gazebo, I copy the .dae file to my Gazebo "models" directory (see below). I then add the terrain to the .world file so that it is guaranteed to be static.

```
  <model:physical name="hill">
   <xyz>5.0 -5.0 0.1</xyz>
   <rpy>0 0 0</rpy>
   <static>true</static>
   <body:trimesh name="hill">
      <geom:trimesh name="hill">
        <scale>1.0 1.0 1.0</scale>
        <mesh>ground_profile_test.dae</mesh>
        <visual>
           <scale>1.0 1.0 1.0</scale>
           <mesh>ground_profile_test.dae</mesh>
        </visual>
      </geom:trimesh>
  </body:trimesh>
 </model:physical>
```

**NOTE**: You must configure your Gazebo media paths correctly. See [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/GazeboConfiguration).

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-01-23**:
Ah I see, that at least clears up why I'm having those annoying problems. I'll update my Blender/COLLADA question accordingly. Thanks for the quick and enlightening answer.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-01-23**:
Oh yes, I've received that error before. The problem comes from Blender > 2.49b. I don't know what's different in the COLLADA exporter, but it doesn't work. Thus, I still use Blender 2.49b. I have a "build" machine to do the exporting, so I can still use 2.6 on my main machine.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-01-23**:
So the Blender .dae export works as intended for you? I get this if I use the .dae exported from Blender 2.61 directly: http://bit.ly/hills_bl . OTOH, if I just open this in meshlab and save as .dae again, I get this: http://bit.ly/hills_ml (but material info is obviously lost).

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-12-12**:
Are there any other options for rough terrains in Gazebo? The tutorial linked here seems old.